# ¿Cómo convertir un tipo String a Float o Int?

Tags: python, string, coma-flotante, números-enteros

En Python, ¿cómo puedo convertir una cadena `"123.456"` en un número decimal `123.456`? ¿Y cómo una cadena `"32"` a un entero `32`?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int-in-python

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Utiliza [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) para convertir a decimal e [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) para convertir a entero:

```
>>> a="123.456"
>>> float(a)
123.456
>>> int(float(a))
123

>>> b="32"
>>> int(b)
32
```