# ¿Cuál es el error en este bucle?

Tags: python, bucles

Tengo este código:

```
clase = 0

while clase == 0:

    clase = input ("Elige una clase de Héroe: ")

    if clase == 1 or clase == 2 or clase == 3:

        break

    else:

        print ("Elige una maldita clase!")
        clase = 0
```

Y no entiendo porqué si en el input introduzco un `1`, `2` o `3` se va al `else:` en vez de al `if`.

¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: El `input()` retorna un valor tipo `string`. Asi que `string == int: False` y por eso se va al `else`. Tendrías que [convertir la cadena a entero](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/49195/80870) con `int()`

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `input` retorna una cadena. Si el usuario digita la tecla 1, la función `input` te retorna "1", una cadena, no un valor.

Tienes dos alteranativas. La primera es convertir a entero la opción digitada:

```
clase = int(input ("Elige una clase de Héroe: "))
```

Esto tiene el inconveniente de que se produce un `ValueError` si el usuario no presiona un número.

La segunda alternativa es dejar el `input` como está y modificar el `if` para que compare cadenas:

```
if clase == '1' or clase == '2' or clase == '3':
```

Elige una de las dos.