# Cambiar el tipo de dato en el envío de datos junto con imagen a una API REST

Tags: javascript, django, djangorestframework

Un saludo para todos.

Estoy construyendo un chat (sin sockets) con Django y Django restframework usando el sistema de plantilla de Django he creado el campo para envío de los mensajes de texto se una sola sala, adicional puse un botón para permitir al usuario adjuntar una imagen.

El envío de texto funciona sin problema, pero cuando quiero enviar una imagen obtengo un error por tipo de dato errado; cuando la API trata de almacenar la información de la pk del usuario informa que esta recibiendo un str en lugar de un int.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso del envió de texto lo almaceno en un objeto de javascript y uso `JSON.stringify` antes de enviar la data. En el otro caso debo almacenar la imagen en un objeto de tipo `FormData` junto con el resto de la información, lo cual transforma el entero `int` a una cadena de texto `str`.
Eh estado buscando la forma de modificar el dato antes de hacer el envío sin perder la información de la imagen pero no he tenido éxito

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También he buscado la forma de procesar la información en el momento en que la API lo recibe pues como ven en la imagen anterior me genera un `Bad Request`
He modificado el método `dispatch` del `MessageModelViewSet` así como también el método `to_internal_value` del `MessageModelSerializer` pero no he logrado resolverlo.

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar les quedo muy agradecido.

models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='message_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'message'
        verbose_name_plural = 'messages'
        ordering = ['created']
```

serializers.py

```
class MessageModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'content', 'image', 'created']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['username'] = instance.user.get_username()
        data['username_encrypt_md5'] = instance.user.get_username_encrypt_md5
        data['owner'] = instance.user == self.context.get("request").user
        return data
```

views.py

```
class MessageModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageModelSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

chat.js

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('user', idUsuario);
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
for (const file of input.files) {
    formData.append('image', file, file.name);
}
fetch(url,
    {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
            "Accept": "*/*",
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=something'
        },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function (data) {
        // Error FormData convierte el pk del usuario de int a str
        console.log(data);
        addElementMessage(data);
     })
```

Comment: Con base en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49194/c%C3%B3mo-convertir-un-tipo-string-a-float-o-int), intenta `data['owner'] = instance.user == int(self.context.get("request").user)`

Comment: Si, pero el problema es que no sé en que método ejecuto esa acción

Comment: Lo tienes en `serializers.py`.

Comment: Tengo entendido que el método `to_representation` es para modificar el `response` y y necesito modificar el `request` antes de que el sistema lo analice. Voy a intentarlo de todas formas a ver que pasa.

Comment: Hice el ajuste pero me sigue presentando el mismo error

Comment: Desconozco Python y Django, no sé si puedas modificar directamente los datos en `request`.